# レスポンシブル　iOS 横幅が合わない。

Tags: ios, html, css

レスポンシブル　Webページを作ったのですが、iPhoneのみ、なぜか横に幅ができ横スクロールしてししまいます。画像なども見切れる（左よりになる。）
CSSでwidthなどは `100%` 等に指定していても `20%` ぐらい必ず右に隙間ができてスクロールされてしまう。
解決方法があったら教えてください。

viewportは指定しています。

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1):

viewportを以下のように指定してますか？
これがないと、ブラウザの横幅が拾えません。ヘッダーにこのmetaタグを追加してください。

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```